# Terminal inside sublime text

Tags: terminal

A long time ago when I used gedit, I was able to have a built in terminal at the bottom. This allowed me to sftp into my server, edit code, and then compile it in the terminal right inside the application connected to the same server.

Right now I'm running Sublime Text 2 and putty externally, it's annoying switching between the two.

Is there a terminal that I can install in Sublime that I could SSH into my remote server with?

Comment: Not a stable one, no: https://github.com/wuub/SublimePTY

Comment: Jesus that looks atrocious haha. Thanks though.

Comment: It doesn't look too bad, but it is a bit laggy and doesn't like my color scheme: http://i.imgur.com/RZrc9Zv.png

Comment: Actually that's not so bad, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Blender's comment, please look at the [Sublime Forum - Terminal inside Sublime Text (jps!)](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11271) summarizing the options as:

- SublimeREPL (not a full terminal. only simple commands)
- SublimePTY (attempt at a full terminal, but project has been idle)
- ConEmu (Windows)